# listen for router change via useEffect in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get an useEffect to execute some code when a user changes the page via the navigation.

My problem is that the useEffect does not execute on the route change (does not show up in console). It does only show up on the first initial page load and never after

I used the [google analytics](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics) example from nextJS

This is my simple _app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "./styles/css.scss";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { useEffect} from "react";



const Child: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("called");

  }, [router.events]);
  return (
    <>
      <Child>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Child>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank to @Faruk answer, I was able to find that it was possible but I had to use those router.events.on inside my hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
      console.log("route change routeChangeComplete");
    });
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", () => {
        console.log("stoped");
      });
    };
  }, [router.events]);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for the new App router version of NextJS. Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#migrating-from-nextrouter

Answer (score 21):

I was able to get this working more simply, by listening for changes to `router.asPath`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect fired!', {asPath: router.asPath});
  }, [router.asPath]);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `routeChangeStart`, `routeChangeComplete` and `routeChangeError` events to do some functionality whenever the route is changing.

Here I use NProgress to show slim progress bar, if you want you can try the same thing and get some idea about how its working or you can just log some data, `() => { console.log("route change start") }`

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import { Router } from 'next/dist/client/router'
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
  NProgress.start()
})
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
  NProgress.done()
})
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => {
  NProgress.done()
})
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        Welcome to my App
      </h1>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: @Maxime Ghéraille, you might not need to use useEffect since if you are using the routes changes in your _app.js its rendering everytime route changes automatically, I noticed it from my own app, I just recommend you to try and tell me if it works, thanks, also if its work can you mark my post as the answer? thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
import  { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = ({ }) => {
  const router = useRouter(),
  [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

  const enableReady = async (loc) => {
  setReady(false);
  console.log("enableReady", loc);
};

const disableReady = async (loc) => {
  console.log(".....");
  await sleep(3);
  console.log("done");
  setReady(true);
  console.log("disableReady", loc);
};

useEffect(() => {
  router.events.on("routeChangeStart", async () => await enableReady("star a"));
  router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", async () => await disableReady("com a"));
  router.events.on("routeChangeError", async () => await disableReady("err a"));

  return () => {
    router.events.off("routeChangeStart", async () => await enableReady("star b"));
    router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", async () => await disableReady("com b"));
    router.events.off("routeChangeError", async () => await disableReady("err b"));
  };
}, [router.events]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useLocation`  for this

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {

    alert(location );// this will be called whenever the route changes 

  }, [location ]);
  return (
    <>
      <Child>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Child>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: hi, this does require to use react-router-dom + it gives an error in nextJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined.

Comment: yeah you need eact-router-dom

Comment: sorry I completely overlooked the Nextjs part of your question , but still try react-router-dom

Comment: You made reference to `useLocation`, but didn't specify the package that makes it available or defines it